# How to prevent anonymous users not viewing any webform content

Tags: webforms

I have created a web form contact us page. Anonymous users can see the contact us page at xxx.com/node/add/webform. After they submit the webform, they can see the content of the form at xxx.com/node/x.

In People > Permission page, I have given two permissions to anonymous users:

1. webform: create new content
2. View published content

If I uncheck number 2, anonymous users can not view anything. I also went to structure > content types > webform and I did not see anything there to set the permission.I also searched google and I could not find the specific answer.

Do you know how I can prevent anonymous users not viewing the web form published content except adding the webform content?

Comment: you can make a simple rule. That will redirect user to specific page after webform submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to look at the [content_access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) module which will allow you to configure default access control on a per node type or per node basis.

**Content Access:**

> This module allows you to manage permissions for content types by role and author. It allows you to specifiy custom view, edit and delete permissions for each content type. Optionally you can enable per content access settings, so you can customize the access for each content node.

[image]